# Error - I installed Ubuntu 64-bit on a 32-bit system

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

My problem is this: I want to install Ubuntu on a 32-bit netbook and a 64-bit notebook, so what do I do now? Install the 32-bit? Do I have to delete the 64-bit Ubuntu on the netbook? Or in the USB installation will I get the option to delete the old one? I am a new Ubuntu user. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install a 64-bit OS on a 32-bit machine but you can install a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit machine. Yes, your earlier installation of a different type will be overwritten(i.e deleted).